# Minimum steps for a chess knight to capture n pawns that are moving down simultaneously?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, backtracking, chess

This is a homework question, but I don't really know how to go about tackling it and would appreciate any tips, as I haven't found any very similar problems online.

Basically, I have to come up with a program that takes in positions of a number N of pawns on a 8x8 chess board, and the position of a single knight, and then determine whether it's possible for the knight to capture every pawn (while moving in standard chess knight L-shaped fashion) and what is the minimum amount of moves to do so; moreover, every turn all the pawns move 1 square down the board simultaneously. If any of the pawns makes it to the last row, it is promoted into a queen and the knight loses immediately if it doesn't capture it as soon as it is promoted. The knight also loses if it ends a turn in a position where it is to be attacked by any pawn the next turn.

This seems similar to a knight's tour problem, but I'm not sure how to deal with the fact that the targets the knight has to go to are always moving and also making sure the knight doesn't get captured. I first tried solving it with backtracking which seems to be a common approach for this sort of chess problem, but I couldn't really come up with anything. Then what I thought of as a possible, if very inefficient, solution with dynamic programming was to solve the knight's tour problem for each possible starting square for the knight (maybe memoizing the results as a 64x64 array) and then whatever square the knight is on I would know the minimum amount of steps to get to any other square (where a pawn might be). With this I could check which, if any, pawns could be captured before the closest pawn to the bottom row is promoted to queen (by comparing the number of steps for the knight to reach the pawn to the number of steps for the pawn to reach the final row). However, this is not a perfect solution either, as memoizing the knight's tour in this manner would only save the minimum amount of steps taken and not the actual paths (which would presumably take up a lot of memory) and thus I wouldn't be able to check whether the knight is going to be captured by a pawn at some point during the path.

Comment: *"I first tried solving it with backtracking which seems to be a common approach for this sort of chess problem, but I couldn't really come up with anything."* Well, backtracking search seems like the most sensible thing to try, so what specifically did you have trouble with when you tried to do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that a breadth-first search would be fine.

The knight has at most eight possible moves at each position and there are at most seven turns before some pawn gets promoted. So that's at most about two million possibilities to search, but in practice there would be a lot fewer.

You only need about N+6 bits to describe a position (64 possible knight locations and a bit vector of which pawns are still alive). Since N cannot be more than eight (otherwise the knight can't capture them all before one gets promoted), you can keep track of all the seen positions and the immediate predecessor of each one with a vector of 16384 `short`s.

Comment: You also need to know how far the pawns have advanced so far, so N+6 bits is not enough. The knight's position doesn't uniquely determine how many turns have occurred.

Comment: Well if we haven't won yet we can discard the array for N-1 moves once we have processed it.

Comment: @kaya3: when you do a breadth-first search, the entire fringe is at the same depth. So you always know how many moves have elapsed.

Comment: @rici Yes, if you also keep track of how many moves have elapsed in a separate variable; but how do you know when to increment it? The traditional way of implementing a breadth-first search is to have a queue where on each iteration you poll the next unvisited state and enqueue its children. You don't necessarily know when that next unvisited state is at the same depth as the previous one, or one move deeper.

Comment: @kaya3: you increment the level counter when you've processed as many children as you added since the last time you incremented the level counter.